# Unable to Retrieve “two option” values on plugin - CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I'm unable to retrieve "two option" field's selected value on plugin using the following code

```csharp
bool? update = entity.GetAttributeValue<bool?>("new_updatecontacts");

bool  update = entity.GetAttributeValue<bool>("new_updatecontacts");

if (update)
{
    ..................
}
```

Is there any other way of retrieving the same? I have already posted the same question, but did not get a definite answer, so am asking again.

Comment: It is most likely that the value does not exist in the entity property bag - are you sure it is there?

Comment: I generated the early bound entity class using the following command 
CrmSvcUtil.exe /url:https://URL/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc /out:Xrm.cs /username:ME /password:Password /namespace:Xrm /serviceContextName:XrmServiceContext, This class did have the attribute in it. I mean if this is the way to check.

Comment: You are running this in a plugin. The value may not be there unless you explicitly grab it from CRM - try something like if(entity.Attributes.Contains("new_updatecontacts")) { //do something }

Comment: I did try that, but the "if" condition fails. So How to go about it?

Comment: I mean I had that "if" condition in place and just had an exception thrown, it never hit the "if".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, a plugin only contains the values for fields that have been added/updated. For other events you get other properties but let's go with that for now.

So if you want to be sure you have a value, you need to run off to CRM to get a copy.

```
var context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
var serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
var service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.InitiatingUserId);

var target = context.InputParameters["Target"] as Entity;
if (!target.Contains("new_updatecontacts"))
{
    target = service.Retrieve(target.LogicalName, target.Id, new ColumnSet(new [] { "new_updatecontacts", "other_required_fields_here" });
}

//now you know it is present
```

It is worth checking if it is there first as it saves a server hit.

Comment: Hi Glosrob,Thanks a ton for informing me the same. You were right,the attribute was not even retrieved in the first place for it to be updated. The funny thing is none of the field's (attributes') value is obtained without the code "service.retrieve". May i know why? I mean is there a problem with the organization.svc or could it be something else? Cos the values for the attributes are retrieved at times and not sometimes.

Comment: Check out Pre-Images; you can get all the values of the entity from a Pre or Post image.

Comment: There is no problem with Organization.svc, as glosrob said, only the attributes that changed are returned. Registering images is more efficient that service.Retrieve (easier too)